# Is there a mathematical symbol for evidence?

Tags: probability, notation, bayesian

I'm currently writing a short paper on the evidence needed to hold a probability function(in the Bayesian sense) objectively and trying connecting it to entropy.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anywhere in the literature a standard symbol for "evidence". Does there exist one? It seems unusual to me that there isn't a symbol for evidence. Or something somewhat similar. The best one I can think of is e, but clearly that won't work.

Comment: I don't think there is such a symbol. Even if there were I would probably recommend against using it. Clear prose is your best bet trying to explain probability. If you have theorems to prove that require a formal definition of "evidence" you can invent a symbol for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the best symbol I can think of is e, but clearly that won't work.